# I have trouble on installing 64bit windows 8.1 on my laptop

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, 64-bit, software-update

I have a disc image of an installer for 64 bit windows 8.1. I mount it and it displays the content. I double click on the "set-up" application and it does not run. It says "This app can not run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher."

I got the installer from our university's website so it is legitimate.

I also checked if my processor can handle 64 bit operating system and it is x64 based.

I don't know what is the cause of the problem. Please help me guys. I need to upgrade my operating system as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Would it be possible to take a picture of the error? That error message is really generic.

Comment: Are you currently running a 32 bit version of windows?

Comment: What is your exact processor?

Comment: Burn the image to disk and boot from the disk instead of trying to run the 64-bit setup.exe in your existing (assuming here) 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble in directly running the installer you can try creating an installation media and apply the update. You can follow the below article to create installation media for Windows 8.1

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media